# Trim TimeSpan to minutes

Tags: c#, trim, truncate, timespan

Looking for a quick and versatile method to trim TimeSpan to minutes, or better to seconds, milliseconds in C#.

At the moment I use the following method:

```
/// <summary>
///Trims TimeSpan with the specified accuracy.
/// </summary>
///<param name = "roundTicks"> cropping accuracy:
/// <code>
///TimeSpan.TicksPerDay - clipping days
///TimeSpan.TicksPerHour - clipping hours
///TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute - clipping minutes
///TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond - clipping seconds
///TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond - clipping millisecond
/// </code>
public static TimeSpan Trim(this TimeSpan time, long roundTicks) => TimeSpan.FromTicks(time.Ticks - time.Ticks % roundTicks);

//call
var d1 = new DateTime(2022, 02, 24, 5, 7, 3);
var d2 = DateTime.Now;
var timeDays = (d2-d1).Trim(TimeSpan.TicksPerDay);
var timeDaysAndHours = (d2-d1).Trim(TimeSpan.TicksPerHour);
var timeDaysAndHoursAndMinutes = (d2-d1).Trim(TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute);
```

Comment: What language is that? I am sorry, I suspect that the reason why you haven’t got any reactions to your question is the users who know about that language didn’t see it.Always mention the programming language and also add the appropriate language tag.

Comment: It's C #, but I can't find where to put the language for the question?

Comment: `DateTime.Now` is a `DateTime` not a `TimeSpan`, thus your extension method won't work for sample call as it is defined for `TimeSpan`, which you get, for instance, by taking the difference between two `DateTime`s (ex: `sometime - someothertime`). Otherwise, your "call", with type corrected, would return the delta time rounded down to the nearest hour. To change this, replace `TimeSpan.TicksPerHour` with other constants such as `TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute` or `TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond`.